# filtering pandas dataframe with array of unique values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas DF with two columns, one columns consists of unique filenames and the other consists of that filenames' label. I also have a numpy array of the filenames that i can use for training my model. I need to extract the labels from the DF that match the filenames i can use. I tried this:

```
x = []

for i in nparray:
  for j in DF['filenames']:
    if DF['filenames'][j] == nparray[i]:
      x.append(DF['label'][j])
```

if I do this i get a key error with the name of the first filename of the DF

Comment: Please add input data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like these

```
DF[DF['filenames'].isin(nparray)]
```

To get only label column

```
DF[DF['filenames'].isin(nparray)]['label']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list(DF[DF['filenames'].isin(nparray)]['label'])
```

Will give you a list with `label`s in `DF` where it's value in `filenames` is in `nparray`

Comment: Thanks, this also works